# C# ASP.net How to access new classes from code behind, not kept in APP_CODE, but kept in same folder as code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, outer-classes

I want to create classes that are separate files (not code within he aspx.cs) file, and I do not want to put them in the APP_CODE directory.

I want the separate class files to reside in the same directory as the main code behind file (aspx.cs).

Each class will perform a function.

I may be using these classes improperly so correct my terminology if I am wrong.

What I want is for many of my functions (methods) to be code in files outside my code behind file and simply called from withing the code behind file. I believe I do this by creating classes. Sorry if I am wrong I am quite a bit rusty.

Each class (or whatever it is called) will be named according to its function.

I am so ignorant of how to do this, I really need a tutorial. I cannot find any, or any other answers that address exactly what I want to do. I believe this is called an "outer class". Where as an "inner class" is written inside of another class.

I know how to write a class file, I just don't know how to access it from the code behind file aspx.cs

Comment: Is it a website project or a web application project?

Comment: Website Project

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the file path matters, but you need to use the namespace right. If you have the Question class defined within the TestProject.Pages namespace in your project, like this:

```
namespace TestProject.Pages
{
    public class Question
    {
    }
}
```

Then you add this line to your aspx.cs file, which lets that code see the namespace you used above:

```
using TestProject.Pages
```

and you should be able to access the Question class.

Comment: OK, then another question. Looking at my code behind file there is no namespace declaration. So, does a program need one to work. The program does work, and it is a web site running on an IIS 7 server. So, do I just need to add a namespace if I want to access the classes I create?

Comment: It tells me the using statement is unnecessary.

Comment: If the code in both files is in the same namespace, it doesn't need the using statement. The code will work exactly the same event if the using statement is unnecessary.

Comment: I may not know how to use, or add namespaces in my project. If this is true, then not sure if it's ignorance of Visual Studio, C#, or asp.net. I tried adding a namespace statement to all the files but still same problem. I am mobile right now, so next time I can get my development laptop connected to WiFi I will upload a sample of how I am trying to use the namespace. In the meantime, any suggestions applicable to some configuration needed to get Visual Studio or my project to actually use the namespace?

Answer (score -1):

It's simple!

// you can access classes that are in different folders. by mention the folder in which class resides then put '.' then class name.

e.g :

```
myfolder.myclass cls = new myfolder.myclass();
```

Comment: To answer Mason's question about the type of project, I believe it is a website project. Actually not sure what the difference is. But to guess, a web application would be more like an intranet program that uses a web browser as it's interface. It does not negotiate a connection or do hand shaking. It just works on a PLAN.

Comment: That's a typo. I meant LAN.

Comment: @Mike no, that's completely wrong. A website project is not compiled into DLLs before deploying and has no csproj file. A web application project is compiled to DLLs and has a csproj file. It has nothing to do with handshaking or Internet vs LAN. Both are accessed through a web browser.